# Delphi/ADO: How to read Information from an Active Directory with SSL Authentication?

Tags: delphi, ssl, active-directory, delphi-2010

I am working on a project that needs to read some information from an Active directory.
I used the components TADOconnection and TADOcommand to get it to work.

Current Code with sensitive Information Hidden as XX:

```
conADO : TADOConnection
cmdADO1 : TADOCommand

 var
 SQL, DOMAIN: WideString;
 Information: _recordset;

 begin

 DOMAIN := '''LDAP://OU=XX,OU=XX,dc=XXX,dc=XXX, dc=de''';
 try
   lst1.Clear;

   cmdADO1.Connection := conADO;
   conADO.Connected := true;
   SQL := 'select mail from ' + DOMAIN + ' where objectclass=' + '''person''' + ' and objectclass=' +
  '''user'' ORDER by cn';
   cmdADO1.CommandText := SQL;

    Information := cmdADO1.Execute;

    while Information.EOF = False do
    begin
      if Information.Fields[0].Value <> NULL then
         ShowMessage(Information.Fields[0].Value);

         Information.MoveNext;
    end;

 finally
   conADO.Connected := False;
 end;
end;
```

It works like this but it doesnt ask for any authentication (my guess that it uses the default cresedentials that from my service account)

When I try to change the Domain to `LDAPS//: ....` I get the Error:

```
       "Table does not exist."
```

So is there any way to SSL authentication with ADO components?

Comment: Authentication would be done in the ADOConnection, as it's what would actually connect. What are you using for a `ConnectionString`?

Comment: The ConnectionString is:

`Provider=ADsDSOObject;Encrypt Password=False;Mode=Read;Bind Flags=0;ADSI Flag=-2147483648`

However I can even get the Information like I said in the question without authenticication and and want to use SSL for it (LDAPS).